# Does objective c compiler automatically set retain in property setting methods?

Tags: objective-c

In `Objective C`, if I have a class, within the class a method that creates a string using some convenience method and set the property `NSString` pointer to the newly created string. In this case, because the string is created using convenience method, it will have one owner which is the autorelease pool. When I assign the string to the property `NSString` pointer, will the compiler set the property as an owner to that string by inserting a retain call?

I think it should. Otherwise, when the autorelease pool is drained, the string will be released. However, if the object of the class still lives outside the autorelease pool, the property will point to memory that is already released, which causes a premature deallocation issue. In this case, there should be a retain call to set the object as a new owner to the string. Am I right on this?

Comment: it would be nice if you provide few lines of code to illustrate your question

Comment: I recommend declaring the "@property", and adding weak/strong, atomic/nonatomic, read/readwrite as you want them, which makes it clear to you and any future reader what will happen, instead of relying on what you think should happen.

Comment: The truth is that Apple has mucked with the defaults for property attributes several times, so it's best to not rely on a default.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "assign the string to the property NSString pointer" is a bit ambiguous.  If you use the property setter either as a method invocation or with dot syntax the memory management specified or defaulted for the property will be used.  If you assign directly to the underlying pointer, then you are bypassing the property attributes and the retain state will remain whatever it was before assignment.

Comment: In the case of ARC, your last sentence is wrong (or misleading). A strong property implies a strong instance variable, therefore it does not matter if you use the property setter, or assign to the instance variable directly: In both cases you create a strong reference that increases the retain count.